# Finding slope over time for each participant in a long-form data set

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, linear-regression

I would like to compute the linear regression and maximum likelihood slopes for each participant. This [fine response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567564/calculating-slopes-of-fluorescence-over-time) explains how to do that for wide-form data, but mine are "long-form" longitudinal data, similar enough to [Singer & Willet's](http://gseacademic.harvard.edu/~alda/) data on alcohol use among teens:

```
alcohol1 <- read.table("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/r/examples/alda/data/alcohol1_pp.txt", header=T, sep=",")
```

Where, to exemplify, I would like to determine the linear regression (OLS) and maximum likelihood (MLE) slopes for `alcuse` across `age` for each `id` within the `alcohol1` data set.

Output can be either another data frame in which each `id` has a corresponding variable that is the slope for their values or a column added to the original `alcohol`a data that is this slope for each instance of that participant.

Like Singer & Willet, my participants do not all have the same number of occurences and some missing data, so I would like to account that as well.

Comment: It's not clear to me *what* you want to model. What is your response, what is (are) the predictor(s)? Can you edit your post to include the explicit linear model?

Comment: See answers like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33870137/1222578 . Beyond your question about how to achieve this, I think you should also look into mixed/hierarchical linear models with random slopes, rather than fitting completely separate regressions to each participant.

Comment: Thank you, @Marius. I am not facile with `dplyr`--nor its use here. You are right that the "actual" analyses will focus on MLMs, but for this purpose my colleagues and I want to look more exploratively at individuals based on their slopes.

Comment: If you're not used to `dplyr` then some of the other answers to the same question might be better, e.g. the answer that suggests using `lme4::lmList` (it's from a mixed effects package but that particular function does standard regressions).

Comment: So run a GLM for each id: E.g.: `alcohol1.id1 <- alcohol1[ which(alcohol1[$id == 1), ]` etc.? if I understand correctly, `lmList` is set up better for wide-form data. But I am not an expert on any of this!

Comment: `lmList` is set up for long-form data. In the linked example, `state` is equivalent to `id` in your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't opposed to using tidyverse functions:

```
dat <- data.frame(list(id = c(rep("id1",3),rep("id2",3),rep("id3",3)),
                       age = rep(c(14, 15, 16), 3),
                       alc.use = pi + rnorm(.5,1, n = 9)))
head(dat)
   id age  alc.use
1 id1  14 3.887784
2 id1  15 5.388763
3 id1  16 3.348683
4 id2  14 3.624546
5 id2  15 4.494489
6 id2  16 5.103788

group_by(dat, id) %>% summarize(b0 = coef(lm(alc.use ~ age))[1],
                                b1 = coef(lm(alc.use ~ age))[2])

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  id        b0     b1
  <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 id1     8.25 -0.270
2 id2    -6.69  0.740
3 id3    21.1  -1.14
```

Comment: Thank you, @Dij. Is there a way to allow for `id` with different numbers of repeated data? I.e., when difference `id`s have different number waves of `alcuse`?

Comment: Yes, `group_by` handles that internally. After the grouping you could have a list of 4 time/age points for participant 1, 3 datapoints for the next participants, etc. When you call `summarise`, it will produce one row for that whole group regardless and does not matter how many rows it collapsed upon for each level of the grouping variable